# How to mark as read all mail in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I have hundreds of unread emails in my Gmail account and I want to mark them all as read.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a step-by-step solution here, and it works:

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/btl/how-to-mark-all-unread-emails-as-read-in-gmail-and-more/80754

- Press the search button: `is:unread`
- Click the down-arrow in the "`select`" button, then choose "`all`."
- Click where it says "`Select all conversations that match this search`."

[image: no spoiler, please]

- Click the "More" button, then click "`Mark as read`."

Answer (score -1):

Using `is:unread` lists all unread emails from all categories, including Promotions and Spam. If you want to mark only your Primary emails as read, use

[image]

This only lists the emails from selected category which makes marking as read task easier.

Comment: Good, but this only shows your unread messages. The question was: How do you mark those messages as read?

Answer (score -4):

You can create a filter for all the unread email (I'm assuming that you might have several pages of unread emails) and set it as read at the end of the filter creation options.